# JApplet - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception, japplet

I do not manage to get my applet run. googeling for that issue, I find hundreds of posts about being aware of parameter `codebase`.

In my opinion all is right, what could cause the problem?

Both, scrabble.jar and Applet.html reside in http://localhost/applet

```
Error message: ClassNotFoundException: tki.scrabble.ui.swing.AppletUI.class
```

---

```html
<applet 
    codebase="http://localhost/applet"
    code="tki.scrabble.ui.swing.AppletUI.class"
    archive="scrabble.jar"
    width=120 height=120>
</applet>
```

My Applet:

```
package tki.scrabble.ui.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import tki.scrabble.Game;

public class AppletUI extends JApplet {

public AppletUI() {
    super();
    init();
}
public void init() {
    Game game = new Game();     
    GameUI gameUI = new GameUI(game, 500);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(gameUI, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    AppletUI ui = new AppletUI();
    ui.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `tki.scrabble.ui.swing.AppletUI.class` exists in the right path inside `scrabble.jar`?

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: yes, I crosschecked the path within jar several times. It's also a runnable jar (containing a JFrame-class) and this works fine. It's not homework, it's only private amusement. I started programming the game core, then developed a swing gui. I'd like to build an applet just because this should be easy without any more effort, at least I expected that.